# Passing Parameters to NPM App in Dockerfile with Run Yarn

Tags: docker, heroku, npm, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have an acquired docker file I'm using to deploy graphql-faker to Heroku using a Docker image.

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to pass critical "config parameters" to the graphql-faker app upon startup.

Need to pass these parameters:

```
--extend <URL> 
--forward-headers [Array]
```

Here's the Docekfile as it stands:

```
FROM node:14.3.0-alpine

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/usr/local/bin/graphql-faker"]
WORKDIR /workdir

EXPOSE 9002

RUN yarn global add graphql-faker && \
    yarn cache clean --force
```

Comment: As you've shown it, you should be able to just include them after the image name in a `docker run` command, or as the `command:` in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  (The "command" arguments just get appended to the "entrypoint" command.)

Comment: @DavidMaze this is super helpful.  I didn't realize the "command" would append to my entrypoint.  Thank you!